# How to work with big tables in MySQL + PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

Let's say, we have a MySQL table with user posts. We need to find all post where `user_id=1`and show them descending by date. But the more posts in the table is, the slower will the search happen, right? What if there are 10000 posts in the table, and we need to find just 3 of them. How long will it take? How to optimize? Can you explain please, how to design data right or just a general conception?

Comment: You can use LIMIT X - where "X" is the number you want to limit the search to, and maybe even use pagination. If your table is indexed, then it should be relatively fast. MySQL can handle more than that with generally good performance. LIMIT also accepts a 2nd parameter: `LIMIT 0,3`

Comment: @Fred-ii- and how big sites handle with millions of strings? Is just one MySQL table OK for this?

Comment: I suggest you Google "how to handle millions of records in mysql" there are many results you can read up on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.

A table with 10,000 rows is not a large table.  SQL databases regularly handle queries on tables tens, hundreds, even thousands of times bigger than that.

You need to learn about indexes and partitioning.  A good place to start is with the MySQL documentation on these topics.

Comment: Though, if user_id is primary key, that attribute will already have an index so that wouldn't help.

Comment: @Marcus . . . It would be very poor database design for a column called `user_id` to be the primary key on a table called `posts`.

Comment: Nobody said the table was named posts. Still, that was just a side note. I've already voted up your answer.